# Creating a Modularized SpringBoot app with Gradle

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, module, java-9

I am trying to setup a simple application with one Java module. There is the parent application and a module called "feature".

Despite the IDE autocompletion working ok I keep getting this error during build:

> error: module not found: spring.web

My current setup is:

- Java 12
- SpringBoot 2.5.0-SNAPSHOT
- Gradle 6.8.3

I have done a dozen other apps using "gradle modules" and I am using the same directory structure:

[image]

The parent *build.gradle* is this:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.0-SNAPSHOT'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.mrv'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

java {
    modularity.inferModulePath = true
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
        maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/snapshot' }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':feature')
}
```

The "feature" module-info.java (where the problem is occurring) is this:

```
module com.mrv.modules.feature {
    requires spring.web;
}
```

I based myself on some Maven projects and also the [Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_java_modules_multi_project.html). I also tried to put my main class **ModulesApplication** inside its own module with the same results.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Does the Spring dependency have a `module-info.class`? If not, does it at least have an `Automatic-Module-Name` attribute in the `MANIFEST.MF` file? If the dependency has neither then, as far as I know, Gradle does not recognize it as a module and thus does not put it on the module-path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of hours later I found the solution and it was quite simple: apply **modularity.inferModulePath = true** to all projects:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.0-SNAPSHOT'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.mrv'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
        maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/snapshot' }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    }
    
    /* >>>> MOVED HERE <<<<*/
    java {
        modularity.inferModulePath = true
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':feature')
}
```

This is a [sample project](https://github.com/marcellorvalle/modules-gradle) I made to use as a reference in the future.